# error when using 'npm start' with app created by 'create-react-kotlin-app'

Tags: node.js, kotlin, create-react-app, npm-start

When trying to start up an app that was created by the command line tool 
'create-react-kotlin-app' with 'npm start', I keep getting the following error:

```
kotlin-js failed. do you have kotlin installed?
{
    "code":"ENOENT",
    "errno":"ENOENT",
    "syscall":"spawn C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-
app\\node_modules\\kotlin-compiler\\bin\\kotlinc-js",
    "path":"C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-app\\node_modules\\kotlin-
compiler\\bin\\kotlinc-js",
    "spawnargs":
    [
        "-output",
        "C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-
app\\node_modules\\.cache\\kotlin-webpack\\kotlinApp.js",
        "-source-map",
        "-nowarn",
        "-module-kind",
        "commonjs",
        "-libraries",
        "C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-
app\\node_modules\\@jetbrains\\kotlin-
extensions\\build\\classes\\main\\kotlin-extensions.meta.js:C:\\Use
rs\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-app\\node_modules\\@jetbrains\\kotlin-
react\\build\\classes\\main\\kotlin-
react.meta.js:C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-
app\\node_modules\\@jetbrains\\kotlin-react-dom\\
build\\classes\\main\\kotlin-react-
dom.meta.js:C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-
app\\node_modules\\@hypnosphi\\kotlinx-html-js\\target\\classes\\kotlinx-
html-js.meta.js",
        "C:\\Users\\Aidan\\Desktop\\my-react-app\\src"
    ]
}
```

I have tried installing the Kotlin compiler, npm installing kotlinc-js both globally and locally, and searching the node-modules to see if the files that the system is trying to access are present, and nothing is changing. Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize ahead of time if this is an easily fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Windows is currently unsupported as there's been several reports of this exact problem. Please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CRKA-43.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CRKA is our public issue tracker.

[Updated on 04.11.2017] The issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As leonya pointed out, it's a windows issue.
For the time being you can use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-win10) to compile and run your app with bash, while still using your normal windows for the IDE and everything else.

You can still use windows' cmd and npm to create the project with `create-react-kotlin-app my-app`, then start bash in the same folder (just type `bash` in cmd and hit enter) to run `npm start`

If you don't have WSL installed, follow the instructions in the link above to install Ubuntu on WSL. Then install npm and jdk8:

```
sudo apt-get update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm update -g npm
sudo apt-get install -y default-jdk
```

if you have npm in your windows PATH you may need to add the following alias to bash_aliases in your user's home directory:

```
alias npm=/usr/bin/npm
```

Otherwise bash may try to use the windows npm which obviously won't work.